# in TcxTreeList 16pix free space appears before nodes with imageindex=-1

Tags: delphi, tree, devexpress

i'm using delphi 2010 +DevExpress_v50

I've moved my project from delphi 2009 +DevExpress_v42 thid summer and faced some strange bugs. most of them were resolved, but some...

in TcxTreeList 16pix free space appears before nodes with imageindex=-1 (in v42 wasnt), looks terrible :(

any ideas where to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

well, have found myself :)

As explained in [DevExpress issue Q211083](http://www.devexpress.com/issue=Q211083), this is by design in versions 3 and 5. Space is reserved whenever `ImageList` is assigned.

A workaround is given to handle the `OnGetLevelImages` event to clear the image list on a per-level basis.

Comment: Also would like to say that stateImages works well in same conditions (I am using them as workaround)